# Title Alignment Off Centre

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I am writing this code, first webpage I have built. I have learning along the way but I have hit a block, I feel like it may be a simple block but in my 'scallop' H1 & P I can't get them the align centre, they keep sitting to the left of my site. Can anybody see any faults I am missing?

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #e2bdf9;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #1a0342;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lilita One", cursive;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 88, 5);
  color: white;
}

.TitleHeading {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 150px;
  left: -0.5px;
  bottom: 354px;
  background-color: rgb(9, 158, 123);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.firstbreak {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e2bdf9;
}

.scallop {
  position: relative;
  background: #e26464;
  padding: 50px;
}

.scallop h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.scallop p {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.scallop::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  content: " ";
  background: radial-gradient( circle at 50% 0%, #e26464 25%, #c4dcd1 26%, #c4dcd1 40%);
  background-color: #e26464;
  background-size: 50px 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.after-scallop {
  background: #c4dcd1;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.after-scallop p {
  color: #9089c0;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div class="TitleImage">
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/487671734/photo/contemporary-waiting-room-with-a-yellow-  armchair.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=zGLtlEtfidagJRuVx1SEkS3lkr_5IurCTTTOFb8uk-s=" alt="empty waiting room with a yellow arm chair" style="width: 100%"
    height="350px" />
  <div class="TitleHeading">
    <h1>THOUGHTFUL MINDS</h1>
    <h4>By Nicola</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="firstbreak"></div>

<div id="Services">
  <div class="scallop">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>
      Being all of the above is a wild and fullfiling experiances in life which have lead me into a career in therapy. To get here I have exlpored my own path in life decisions I have made, oportunities taken and those that passed me by. I have found passion
      in helping others explore their journeys.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="after-scallop">
    <h2>Services I offer</h2>
    <br />
    <p style="color: #e26464; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px">
      Tell all your friends and family
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s3.mirror.co.uk/production/email/et/facebook-icon.png" border="0" alt="facebook-icon" width="40" />
      </a>
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s3.mirror.co.uk/production/email/et/twitter-icon.png" border="0" alt="twitter-icon" width="40" />
      </a>
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s3.mirror.co.uk/production/email/et/google-plus-icon.png" border="0" alt="googleplus-icon" width="40" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone identify where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Hey, welcome. It seems to me that it might be related to component's width. You can track this easily browser's developer tools. Try expanding "scallop" class width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position of the `.scallop` class to `absolute`. Then your scallop text will be center.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's worked a treat! Sorry to ask more from you but could you explain how that worked? Just want to make sure I keep learning

Comment: @Alicell95 with relative position, the element get a normal position and your one is to left because of `float:left`. With absolute parameter the element is positioned thanks the parent, here your principal content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `float:left` of the `.TitleHeading` element. It is moved out of the way, due to the `bottom: 354px` but the space it occupied initially is not, so it affects the following elements. I would suggest skipping the `float` completely and try to use flex/grid for structuring the layout of the page.